# Constante error en Visual Studio (c#)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Mi principal problema viene a la hora de compilar mi código, ya que constantemente sale este error:

"1>C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4632,5): warning MSB3026: No se pudo copiar "obj\Debug\Calculadora.exe" en ".\Calculadora.exe". Se iniciará el reintento 1 dentro de 1000ms. El proceso no puede obtener acceso al archivo '.\Calculadora.exe' porque está siendo utilizado en otro proceso. El archivo se ha bloqueado por: "Calculadora (2984)"

Lo soluciono momentáneamente cerrando VS, borrando la carpeta bin y "matando" el proceso de mi aplicación desde el task manager, pero es momentáneo, ya que apenas hago un minimo cambio en el codigo, vuelve a aparecer este error y debo volver a hacer el mismo proceso de antes.

Ya e probado:

*activando y desactivando la configuración de seguridad de ClickOne

*excluir la carpeta Bin del proyecto

*Crear un método para llamar un Form especifico en vez de hacerlo directamente ( por alguna razón vi esto en un video y funciono momentáneamente igual)

*Reiniciando la computadora

*cambiar el nombre del proyecto

No e encontrado solución en ningún foro ni video

imagen del error posterior a la compilación:
[image: imagen del error posterior a la compilación:]

Comment: La imagen la puedes poner directamente y adicional si ya intentaste realizar el borrado de carpetan bin y obj es mejor rehacer el proyecto es decir volver a crear una solucion y copiar y pegar codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Estimado colega, intenta lo siguiente:

- Cierra completamente el `Visual Studio 2022 Community`
- Ve a la carpeta de tu proyecto y borra las ubicaciones `/obj` y `/bin`
- Abre nuevamente `Visual Studio 2022 Community`
- Regenera el `Proyecto` nuevamente

Puedes usar de referencia este post el cual contiene un error como el que mencionas. En ocasiones el .exe se bloquea provocando este molesto error.

Ref. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/es-ES/0523695c-5156-4a4e-8b86-475831b591c8/error11-no-se-pudo-copiar-quotobjdebugconsultorexequot-en?forum=vcses

Espero sea de ayuda!

Comment: Disculpa mi ignorancia, pero a que te refieres con "Regenerar" el proyecto, y como se hace, Muchas gracias!

ya habia revisado ese foro igualmente, sin embargo ninguna de las respuestas soluciono mi error lamentablemente

Comment: No te preocupes, te brindare la guía para regenerar el proyecto colega, Primero para regenerar el proyecto debes dirigirte al menú -> Compilar -> Volver a Generar el Proyecto.

Una vez Regenerado el proyecto realiza en la misma opcion de menu Compilar -> Recompilar Solución

Cuando hayas finalizado esos pasos ya debería haberse compilado tu proyecto.

Si te aparece el mismo error y si deseas puedes compartirme tu Repositorio para validar donde se encuentra el problema, si es un problema local del VS o un problema de codigo fuente.

Saludos colega!

Comment: Sigue apareciendo el mismo error mi estimado, como puedo compartirte mi repositorio?

Comment: Hola estimado, disculpa la tardía respuesta podrías subirlo a Github o compartirme el mismo por email jesrrel1989.1989(arroba)gmail(punto)com, si arreglo tu código te explicare en detalle que operaciones realice y como solventar inconvenientes recurrentes que suelen presentarse en Visual Studio Community 2022

Comment: Seria bueno si puedes compartirlo como te proponen en un repositorio publico en GitHub.com asi podemos ayudarte. Te puede servir [Ayuda > Crear un repositorio en Github](https://docs.github.com/es/get-started/quickstart/create-a-repo)

Comment: lamentablemente, no puede solucionar el problema, al parecer era debido a un problema directamente de Visual Estudio Community 2022, igualmente lo solucione creando un nuevo proyecto y copiando el codigo (no creo que fuera la mejor solucion pero al parecr no encontre otra)

Answer (score 0):

Mira, creo que eso ocurre por lo siguiente,

Estas intentando compilar, mientras que aun sigue ejecutándose la aplicación que intentas compilar,

Al estar ejecutándose el .exe, ese archivo está abierto, por lo que no puedes escribir en el mientras no cierres (el proceso asociado que ejecuta), porque se quedó abierta la app por un descuido, o bien colgada por un error, pero se quedo procesándose igualmente.

Comprueba si puedes cerrarla desde la barra de tareas, o busca la aplicación/proceso en el administrador de tareas del sistema, cierrala o máta el proceso si es necesario (kill process) (cerrar forzosamente, con totalidad) y vuelve entonces a intentar compilar la solución.

Ok, eso ya lo has hecho .. ahora..

Mira, a parte, comprueba que al cerrarse la app, no deje subprocesos abiertos, y asignaciones de memoria pendiente de que se cierren subprocesos que haya llamado la aplicación, ni procesamientos latentes, inconclusos, ni objetos sin cerrar. Fuerza por codigo el cerrar, los hilos, procesos, Forms, etc. que haya instanciado tu app.

Integra codigo, que detenga si es necesario el proceso de cerrar la aplicación, hasta que se haya completado los procesos de guardar datos en disco (serializacion), cerrar otros forms, hilos de ejecución instanciados, procesos CMD instanciados por tu app, y despues, cierras la app por codigo, con Aplication.Exit().

Otro asunto es, el Collector de memoria del sistema, no libera tu memoria, hasta que sea que ya no te quede memoria libre, así muy extremo el asunto,

Si tu app capta mucha memoria muy rapidamente, o de forma relativamente descontrolada, puede dejar en estado de falla ese proceso, y generar fallos a la hora de intentar compilar, o ejecutar nuevamente tu app.

Para eso hace un tiempo buceando en la red encontre un codigo, que fuerza al collector a liberar la memoria de la app, al cerrarla, como medida preventiva, para programas que sepas que no es cuestion de fallas, sino de un uso masivo, rapido y potencialmente ilimitado de la memoria.